# REST API - Put Method best Practices

Tags: api, language-agnostic, asp.net-web-api

I'm designing a restful API using the ASP.NET MVC Web API stack. I am allowing users to create/update/delete records using the relevant HTTP verb. I accept both XML and JSON content types. I'm currently designing the put (update) method on my first endpoint and ran into a question:

I'm wondering what the best practices are for null/empty fields when updating via an API. Should a null/empty field indicate that the consumer is ignoring the field and does not want it updated or that the field which may or may not have previously had a value, should not currently have a value?

Specifically, when a field has data and an update is sent with null/empty data should this field be a) ignored the b) updated and nulled in the DB

I assume that this is something that comes up a lot, but I haven't been able to find any substantive information (mainly due to the lack of an appropriate search term)

Answer (score 2):

The verb `PATCH` has been created for partial update.

I would use `PUT` for full update and `PATCH` for partial ones. If I remember correctly, support for PATCH is in ASP.NET Web API RC.